# Turn off a computer on the network

Tags: networking, cmd.exe, localhost, user

I have tried to follow the instructions on this site: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV_BHcbeKEs
It works if i activate the administrator account on the pc i will turn off and do not have a password on it. But do any of you know how to do this with just a normal administrator account. For example Username: User1
Password: 123
I have tried but it didn´t work out so well.
Here´s what i get:

```
C:\windows\system32>net use \\192.168.x.xx\d$ /user:User1
The Password \\192.168.x.xx\d$ is incorrect.

Type password to connect User1 to 192.168.x.xx:
Error 5 has accured.

Access denied.


C:\windows\system32>net use \\192.168.x.xx\d$
The Password \\192.168.x.xx\d$ is incorrect.

Type Username for 192.168.x.xx: 192.168.x.xx\User1
Type Password for 192.168.x.xx:
Error 5 has accoured.

Access denied.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful tool for shutting down a Microsoft Windows computer from another Microsoft Windows computer is [PsShutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) from Microsoft. If you have a userid and password for an administrator account on the remote system, you should be able to use it without activating the default disabled administrator account.

For the "net use" command you are trying to use before issuing a shutdown command, are you sure you've entered the correct credentials for an account that is in the administrators group on the remote system? Are you trying to use a domain administrator account or a local administrator account on the remote system? If you are certain you have the correct userid and password, if its a domain administrator account try one of the following:

```
    [/USER:[domainname\]username]
    [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
    [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
```

E.g., if you wished to map drive D: on the remote system to drive X: on your system and the IP address of the remote system is 192.168.0.6 and an account in the administrators group on the remote system is User1:

```
net use x: \\192.168.0.6\d$ /user:mydomain\User1
```

If it's a local administrator account on the remote system, try putting in the remote system's name, e.g., "/USER:mypc\User1", if User1 is a local administrator account on the remote system and that system is named mypc.

If you don't know its name, only its IP address, you should be able to get it with the following:

```
nbtstat -A 192.168.0.6
```

Though when I tried a similar "net use" command a moment ago from a Windows 8 system that was not in a [Windows domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain) to access a Windows 8.1 system in a Windows domain on the same LAN I found the command gave me the same "System error 5 has occurred" followed by "Access is denied" when I tried using credentials for a local administrator account on the Windows 8.1 system, e.g. "net use \192.168.0.6\c$ /user:MyPC\AdminUser", but when I tried using the credentials for a domain administrator account, e.g. "net use \192.168.0.6\c$ /user:MyDomain\User2", where User2 was a domain admin account, the command was successful.

Comment: I got it working when i joined all the computers to a domain.